# play a song by using react-native sound

Tags: react-native

```
   import { Sound } from 'react-native-sound'
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import { Button } from 'react-native'

    //import Audio from 'react-native-audio'

    class About extends Component {
      playTrack = () => {
        const track = new Sound('geetha_govindham_song.mp3','', null, (e) => {
          if (e) {
            console.log('error loading track:', e)
          } else {
            //track.play()
          }
        })
        track.play()
      }

      render() {
      console.log("CCCCC", JSON.stringify(Sound));
        return <Button title="play me" onPress={this.playTrack} />

      }
    }
    export default About

    After executing this we got the error like undefined is not a constructor.
```

[image]

Here, i used react-native-sound module for playing mp3 song. But, I got the error like, what shown in the picture. Please give any suggestion to me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try using require?

```
const Sound = require('react-native-sound');
```

Answer (score 0):

you should do default import:

```
import Sound from ‘react-native-sound’
```

You can find the example in the project’s README: https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound/blob/master/README.md